# Can't use the conrod library in my Rust project: can't find crate piston_window

Tags: rust, rust-crates

I'm new to Rust and I'm trying to open a window with the [Conrod library](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/conrod), like they did in the [`canvas.rs` example](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/conrod/blob/308d35e0be4dec6646a52d7cac69145a1d4a5109/examples/canvas.rs):

```
#[macro_use] extern crate conrod;
extern crate find_folder;
extern crate piston_window;

use conrod::{Canvas, Theme, Widget, color};
use piston_window::{EventLoop, OpenGL, PistonWindow, UpdateEvent,     WindowSettings};

fn main() {
    const WIDTH: u32 = 800;
    const HEIGHT: u32 = 600;

    // Change this to OpenGL::V2_1 if not working.
    let opengl = OpenGL::V3_2;

    // Construct the window.
    let mut window: PistonWindow =
    WindowSettings::new("Canvas Demo", [WIDTH, HEIGHT].opengl(opengl).exit_on_esc(true).vsync(true).build().unwrap();
   window.set_ups(60);
}
```

This code works when I use it in a a file in the Conrod project (the one I downloaded from GitHub), but it does not work when I use it in my own code:

```
extern crate conrod;
extern crate piston_window;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

With the following Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "hello_conrod"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["omega"]

[dependencies]
conrod = "0.37.2"
```

Then the compiler tells me this:

```
error: can't find crate for `piston_window` [E0463]
```

I guess my `Cargo.toml` is wrong but I don't have a clue what I should do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the [piston_window crate](https://crates.io/crates/piston_window) from crates.io. Just add this to your `Cargo.toml`, under dependencies:

```
piston_window = "0.51.1"
```

Whenever you see `extern crate _`, you will need to add the crate in your `Cargo.toml` file. The documentation on [crates.io](http://doc.crates.io/manifest.html) shows the different ways of importing crates (locally, optionally, from Git, etc.)

Comment: In the past i tried to add the crate piston_window by adding the pinston_window = "*" to my cargo.toml but it did not work, but i'm still trying  what you just told me, the code is compiling..

Comment: It's working ty, but i don't anderstand, isn't that suppose to work i had piston_window = "*" in the toml ? And how am i suppose to know the last version of the dependecy i'm adding ?

Comment: When you search for a package on crates.io, there is a box with the declaration to copy, for example on the [lazy_static](https://crates.io/crates/lazy_static) page, you can see the line `lazy_static = "0.2.1"`. Don't worry - no-one expects you to learn and remember the versions, but it's bad practice to use "*" because it means your code could break in the future.